# how to upload the images inside a folder 'images' instead of the curent directory in flask

Tags: python, flask

i want to insert all images with flask  inside a folder for example 'images' instead of inserting those images in the "/" directory of project because it seems heavy and it's not professional.

this is my code

```
app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = os.getcwd()
photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, photos)
patch_request_class(app)  

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, '/')
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        file_url = photos.url(filename)
    return file_url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has `app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST']` but doesn't make use of it, so i would suggest doing that.

I would make a directory called `images` in your root application directory, and then follow either of these approaches:

1) Using config

```py
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    target = app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST']
```

2) Without using config

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images')
```

Other considerations:

- You can specify the filepath for `UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST` in a separate config file
- In your current code, `target` is unused, so you will need to pass in that filepath to your image processing